# Iterating a python script through each rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, automation

I am having a python script for sending twitter alerts through slack :-

```
def twitter_setup():
    """
    Utility function to setup the Twitter's API
    with our access keys provided.
    """
    # Authentication and access using keys:
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

    # Return API with authentication:
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api


extractor = twitter_setup()
# We create a tweet list as follows:
tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="**FortniteGame**", count=200)


data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

# We add relevant data:
data['ID'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
data['text'] = np.array([tweet.text for tweet in tweets])
#data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

created_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

data = data[(data['Date'] > created_time) & (
    data['Date'] < datetime.datetime.utcnow())]

my_list = ['Maintenance', 'Scheduled', 'downtime', 'Issue', 'Voice', 'Happy',
           'Problem', 'Outage', 'Service', 'Interruption', 'voice-comms', 'Downtime']

ndata = data[data['Tweets'].str.contains(
    "|".join(my_list), regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)


slack = Slacker('xoxb-3434-4334-fgsgsdfsf')

#message = "test message"
slack.chat.post_message('#ops-twitter-alerts', 'FNWP :' +' '+ ndata['Tweets'] + '<!channel|>')
```

Now I am having a csv file which i am reading in pandas like below

```
       client domain twittername
1.)    EPIC   FNWP   FortniteGame
2.)    PUBG   BLHP   PUBG
3.)    abc    xyx    abhi98358
```

I want to use the same script for each client and i want to iterate through it and suppose first it will do for Fortnite and then for PUBG and then for abhi98358 and in the same way it should go step by step.

Comment: use iterrows or for loop would be sufficient to go through the dataframe

Comment: hey @SarthakNegi i am new in python... I am good with scripting but kind of not good in loops and all.  here two variables i want to make dynamic one is twitter name and one , 'FNWP :' + client name. if you can provide some sample code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: @Georgy I saw this example but i am kind of getting stuck how to pass the client name and twitter name to two different variables. I am messing up at some point.

Comment: @ak333: I can see you are only using column`twitername` on this line of code `tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="**FortniteGame**", count=200)`. So you just want to use iterate on this instead of hardcoding `FortniteGame`?. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal that is exactly what i want.... and on the last line i just want to put domain name instead of  putting FNWP :- , 'FNWP :' +' '+ ndata['Tweets'] . these two things i wwant to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

refer to my solution [converting a python script into a function to iterate over each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876759/converting-a-python-script-into-a-function-to-iterate-over-each-row/52880438#52880438)

```
for index, row in dff.iterrows():
    twt=row['twittername']
    domain = row['domain']
    print(twt)
    print(domain)
    extractor = twitter_setup()
    # We create a tweet list as follows:
    tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name=twt, count=200)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

    # We add relevant data:
    data['ID'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
    data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
    data['text'] = np.array([tweet.text for tweet in tweets])
    #data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

    created_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=160)

    data = data[(data['Date'] > created_time) & (data['Date'] < datetime.datetime.utcnow())]

    my_list = ['Maintenance', 'Scheduled', 'downtime', 'Issue', 'Voice', 'Happy','hound',
               'Problem', 'Outage', 'Service', 'Interruption', 'ready','voice-comms', 'Downtime','Patch']

    ndata = data[data['Tweets'].str.contains( "|".join(my_list), regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)

    print(ndata)
    if len(ndata['Tweets'])> 0:
        slack.chat.post_message('#ops-twitter-alerts', domain  +': '+ ndata['Tweets'] + '<!channel|>')
    else:
        print('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample df:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['FortniteGame', 'PUBG', 'abhi98358']})
```

Sample Iteration:

```
for index, row in t.iterrows():
   print "**" + row['A'] +"**"
```

Sample Output for above:

```
**FortniteGame**
**PUBG**
**abhi98358**
```

For your code:

```
for index,rows in df.iterows():
   tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name=("**" + row['twittername'] +"**"), count=200)
```

Comment: i am gonna try now

Comment: sure thanks a lot i am trying if i wont b able to i will post again

Comment: If it solves what you are looking, do accept and upvote for future users!!

Comment: so its working with your example but when i am trying on mine its saying AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iterows' ............also i don't want to get tweets for all teh user at the same time i want that it should complete the script for one user and then go on the second row and so on,

Comment: still the same issue ...below i have written    for index,rows in t.iterows:
    tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name=(row.twittername ), count=200)
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

    # We add relevant data:
    data['ID'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
    data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
    data['text'] = np.array([tweet.text for tweet in tweets])

Comment: t is the name of my dataframe here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182098/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-ak333).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
twtLst = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   twtDtl = row['client'], row['domain'], row['twittername']
   twtLst.append(twtDtl)
```

twtLst will be a List of tuple and then you access it accordingly like below

```
for twt in twtLst:
    client, domain, twtname = twt
    tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="**" + twtname +"**", count=200)
    #message = "test message"
    slack.chat.post_message('#ops-twitter-alerts', domain + ':' + client +' '+ndata['Tweets'] + '<!channel|>')
```

Comment: in the second chunk i just need the screen name and nothing else so i should do soemthign like tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="**" , count=200) .  right?

Comment: Yes correct, `"**" + twtname +"**"` is just concatenation of 3 strings

Comment: its giving me list of tweets for both the clients at the same time.

Comment: i want that it should do the same process for each of them one by one and not together.